# how to resolve java.lang.ClassCastException: net.sf.json.JSONObject cannot be cast to net.sf.json.JSONObject

Tags: java, json, classcastexception

I am using json-lib-0.9.jar. in view.class i am getting inputstream from the request, setting into request and dorwarding request to Render.jsp, i am not able to understand how to fix this. could someone help me in in order to fix this issue. thanks in advance

*View.class*

```
  import javax.servlet.ServletException;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
  import net.sf.json.JSONObject;
     private void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException { {                 
            if (request.getInputStream() != null) {
               byte[]   bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(request.getInputStream());    
            String resString=new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            JSONObject Json  = JSONObject.fromString(resString);   
            request.setAttribute("META", Json.get("META"))              
     }
      request.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/Render.jsp").forward(request, response);
 }
```

Render.jsp

```
<%@page import="net.sf.json.JSONObject" %>
<%
JSONObject docMeta =  (JSONObject)request.getAttribute("META");%>
```

in this line its throwing

```
java.lang.ClassCastException
java.lang.ClassCastException: net.sf.json.JSONObject cannot be cast to net.sf.json.JSONObject
at org.apache.jsp.jsp.Render_jsp._jspService(PreviewLander_jsp.java:134)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:71)
```

Comment: maybe you are using two different versions of the library. have you tried looking at the dependency tree to see if there are conflicting versions somewhere?

Comment: its dependency has different version jar

Comment: then there's your problem. on the dependency, apply an exclude

Comment: Yes.  This is caused by loading different versions (or the same version) of a class on two different classloaders. The Java runtime system say they are different classes.